# Do I use foreach for 2 different inspection checks in activity diagram?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I am new in doing an activity and currently, I am trying to draw one based on given description.
I enter into doubt on a particular section as I am unsure if it should be 'split'.

Under the "Employee", the given description is as follows:

> Employee enter in details about physical damage and cleanliness on the
> machine. For the cleanliness, there must be a statement to indicate
> that the problem is no longer an issue.

As such, I use a `foreach` as a means to describe that there should be 2 checks - physical and cleanliness (see diagram in the link), before it moves on to the next activity under the System - for the system to record the checks.

Thus, am I on the right track? Thank you in advance for any replies.

[image: activity diagram]

Comment: what is that *foreach* ? It sounds like a loop, but it is in front of a *fork/join*

Comment: yes, the `foreach` is also a fork/join, I was following an example in which it was labelled as foreach too, and hence I jot it down as it it

Comment: strange, where did you see that example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is no valid UML. In order to make it proper you need to enclose the fork/join in a expansion region like so:

[image]

A fork/join does not accept any sematic labels. They just split the control flow into several parallel ones which join at the end.

However, this still seems odd since you would probably have some control for the different inspections being entered. So I'd guess there's a decision which loops through multiple inspection entries. Personally I use regions only for handling interrupts. ADs are nice to a certain level. But sometimes a tabular text (like suggested by Cockburn) is just easier to write and read. Graphical programming is *not* the ultimate answer (unlike 42).

Answer (score 1):

First, the 'NO' branch of the decision node must lead somewhere (at the end?).
After, It differs if you want to show the process for ONE or MULTIPLE inspections. But the most logical way is to represent the diagram for an inspection, because you wrote inspection without S ! If you want represent more than one inspection, you can use decision and merge node to represent loop that stop when there is no more inspection.